# What did the Or Sameach do for Rabbi Yaakov Ruderman?

Tags: agada-stories-legends, quotations, acharonim, hakaras-hatov

I have heard that [Rabbi Yaakov Yitzchak Ruderman](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Yitzchok_Ruderman) of Ner Israel quoted [Rabbi Meir Simcha](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Simcha_of_Dvinsk) (the *Or Sameach* or *Meshech Chochma*) in almost every Torah address to the school. I have heard, further, that he did so as an act of *hakaras hatov* (recognizing beneficence) to Rabbi Meir Simcha for something the latter did for him when he was young. Does anyone know the story?

Comment: Perhaps it is related to this story, printed in the November 1987 edition of the Jewish Observer:                                                          
"One could readily believe the story
told how, as a bachur, Rabbi Ruderman got hold of a copy of a just
published volume of Ohr Somayach
on Zemanim for one night's perusal.
He had no access to a lamp, so he
went through the entire sefer that
night, by the light of the moon. His
poor vision became further damaged
from the experience-but he was
able to quote the sefer copiously for
the remainder of his life."

Answer (score 5):

According to [Rabbi Frand](http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/5768/vayishlach.html?print=1) - Rabbi Ruderman corresponded with the Ohr Sameach.

> Those old enough to remember Rav Ruderman saw a connection to the
>   glory of what European Jewry was in its prime. He corresponded with
>   the Ohr Sameach.

Comment: +1, but I thought there might be something more to it than that. Perhaps not, though!

Answer (score 3):

I learned in Ner Yisroel for a few years, and from what I heard from the Rebbeim, R' Ruderman's affinity for the Ohr Someiach comes from his appreciation of the Ohr Sameach's genius. He learned the entire sefer by moonlight as a bachur. So it was not so much an act of hakaras hatov but of the very high regard he had for the Ohr Sameach's greatness in Torah.